# Сборка статически слинкованного компилятора GCC

Tags: linux, gcc, build, static

Есть ли возможность сборки из исходников статически слинкованного компилятора GCC?

Если да, то какие флаги конфигурации/сборки необходимо указать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Справился с задачей в конце концов. Спасибо ребятам с иностранного [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099893/statically-linked-gcc).

Продублирую решение:

Для сборки статически слинкованного компилятора gcc необходимо при конфигурировании (./configure) указать следующие флаги

```
../configure --disable-shared --disable-host-shared --with-boot-ldflags=-static --with-stage1-ldflags=-static
```